# Meta_query compare operator explanation

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I noticed that there are bunch of operator can be use for compare in meta_query. 
However, I am not quite sure what operator I should use, it is somehow confusing like `=` and `LIKE` operator.

I would like to know what exactly each operator mean, and in what condition I should use them.

```
=
!=
>
>=
<
<=
LIKE
NOT LIKE
IN
NOT IN
BETWEEN
NOT BETWEEN
NOT EXISTS
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The first several work as you would expect:

```
=   equals
!=  does not equal
>   greater than
>=  greater than or equal to
<   less than
<=  less than or equal to
```

---

**LIKE** and **NOT LIKE**

`LIKE` and `NOT LIKE` are SQL operators that let you add in wild-card symbols, so you could have a meta query that looks like this:

```
array( 
    'key' => 'name', 
    'value' => 'Pat', 
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
)
```

This would return all posts where the meta value "name" has the string "Pat". In this case, "Pat" "Patricia" and "Patrick" would all be returned back to you. There's a non-WordPress tutorial explanation [here](http://www.htmlite.com/mysql011.php).

Adding the wildcard character `%` isn't necessary, because it gets added by default like @Herb said in his below [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/118741/22534). Like this: `$meta_value = '%' . like_escape( $meta_value ) . '%';` - see [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L841).

---

**IN** and **NOT IN**

`IN` and `NOT IN` select any matches that are in (or not in) the given array. So you could do something like this:

```
array(
    'key'     => 'color', 
    'value'   => array('red', 'green', 'blue') 
    'compare' => 'IN'
)
```

and it would get all posts that have the color set to either red, green, or blue. Using 'NOT IN' gets the reverse, any posts that have a value set to anything else than what's in the array.

The generated SQL for this would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts_meta WHERE value IN ("red", "green", "blue")
```

---

**BETWEEN** and **NOT BETWEEN**

`BETWEEN` and `NOT BETWEEN` allow you to define a range of values that could be correct, and require you to give two values in an array in your meta_query:

```
array( 
    'key' => 'price', 
    'value' => array(20,30) 
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
)
```

This will get you all posts where the price is between 20 and 30. [This person](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/use-meta-query-to-check-if-a-custom-field-is-between-two-dates) digs into an example with dates.

---

**NOT EXISTS**

`NOT EXISTS` is just like what it sounds - the meta value isn't set or is set to a null value. All you need for that query is the key and comparison operator:

```
array( 
    'key' => 'price', 
    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
)
```

[This person](http://thethemefoundry.com/blog/query-posts-wordpress-false-null-meta-value/) needed to query non-existent meta values, and needed them to play nice with others.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note: If you're using `meta_query` array, your keys should not be prefixed with `meta_`. If you're using `$query->meta_key`, `$query->meta_value`, etc. then these should still retain the prefix.

Comment: I can't seem to find an explanation on what the "IN" compare option does. Any idea how that works?

Comment: @Joe, I don't know why I didn't add anything about "IN" and "NOT IN". I've edited and updated the answer with those comparisons.

Comment: This is a great answer but there are some more options available now-: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: 'EXISTS' , 'REGEXP', 'NOT REGEXP' and 'RLIKE'

Answer (score 13):

Note that when using a meta_compare value of 'LIKE', WordPress automatically wraps the wildcard character ( % ) around the meta_value string. So the 'Pat%' example could fail to return any results.

Comment: is there info about that in the docs somewhere Herb? Should the example change to remove the `%`?

Comment: It should, I actually did that right now, see the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L841), then it gets very clear that Herb is right. @guiniveretoo