# Wordpress loop based on url sting

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-value, query-string

I have a search form on my home page that contains ACF custom fields values in the dropdowns.  On submit the form goes to /test-results/.

On the form I have dropdowns for Price, Region and Title.  If I choose a the first two for example then search a result could be: /test-results/?Price=500-1000&Region=Place2

How I can a use the loop to display posts that are using any of the above selected fields in the url?  So in the example above it would list all posts that contain a price value of "500-1000" and are in the Region called "Place2"

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

**sample test: URL WAS**
/test-results/?Price=&Region=Place3 and did not pull in any test locations that had a acf value set of Place3

```
<?php

$queryPrice = explode('-', $_GET['Price']);
$queryRegion = $_GET['Region'];

$args = array(
    // all your args here
    'post_type'    => 'resorts',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => $queryPrice,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'region',
            'value' => $queryRegion,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),  
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();

?>

<h3>
  <?php the_title();?>
</h3>

<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$_GET['Price']` and `$_GET['Region']` to get the price and region values from the url and add them to your query args. It is rather hard without any code to start from, but try something like

```
$queryPrice = (strpos($_GET['Price'],'-') ? explode('-', $_GET['Price']) : array($_GET['Price'], $_GET['Price']));
$queryRegion = $_GET['Region'];

$args = array(
    // all your args here
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'your_acf_price_field',
            'value' => $queryPrice,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        )
        array(
            'key' => 'your_acf_region_field',
            'value' => $queryRegion,
            'compare' => '=',
        ),  
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Find more info in the [acf documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-query-posts-filtered-by-custom-field-values/) or on [wpse](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/70870/48863)

Comment: i've used your code for the following, see updated question.  When I submit a price or region, I do not get a result. Thoughts?  Probably something I'm doing wrong @alpipego

Comment: i apologize, you were 100% correct. I merely had it cached!  Thank you so much.  I do have one more question however. 

What if the price is a single value and not dashed? So if Its just 5000, as opposed to 5000-10000?  Can It be set to accept both?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I have changed the variable assignment for `$queryPrice`