# Filter posts/pages by user_role array

Tags: wp-query, query, meta-query, comparison

I have made a code for to filter wich pages to show depending on your user_role. Everything was alright. But my customer created NEW roles with similars name/slug.

So now, if some 1 have the role for exemple : Group APTNB, he will be able to see pages with role APTNB_CA because in the slug 'aptnb' is LIKE 'aptnb_ca' in my comparaison.

I have try to explore the possibility to use 'IN' with this post : [Meta_query compare operator explanation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70864/meta-query-compare-operator-explanation)

My script juste exploded when I used it.

Here is my code.

```
global $current_user;

$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
$user_role_query = array();

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($user_roles); $i++) { 
    $user_role_query[] = array(
        'key'=>'attribution_roles',
        'value' => $user_roles[$i],
        'compare'=>'LIKE'
    );
}

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'      => 'suivi_des_comites',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'     => array_merge(
        array( 'relation' => 'OR' ),    // this must be an array
        $user_role_query
    )
);
```

The key, I think would be to rework the array()'s to make it work.

Here some of my print_r();

**print_r($user_role_query);**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => attribution_roles
            [value] => aptnb
            [compare] => LIKE
        )

)
```

**print_r($args);**

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => suivi_des_comites
    [order] => ASC
    [orderby] => title
    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => attribution_roles
                    [value] => aptnb
                    [compare] => LIKE
                )

        )

)
```

In my DB, the page attribute "attribution_roles" return this.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:8:"aptnb_ca";i:1;s:13:"administrator";}
```

When I use the method `LIKE` my query looks like this.

`SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND (( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'attribution_roles' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%administrator%' )) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'suivi_des_comites' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC`

When I use the method `=` my query looks like this.

`SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'attribution_roles' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'administrator' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'suivi_des_comites' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC`

My objective is to fix the issue that [value] => aptnb is the same as [value] => aptnb_ca

and my query would looks like :  FIND all post with custom post_type suivi_des_comites where user_role == 'aptnb_ca' OR user_role == 'aptnb'

It needs to be the exact string and not a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You've used `LIKE` comparison method, that means every similar expression will be matched, including exact string and similar string.

If you want to match exact string, you should use `=` operator.

Example:

```
global $current_user;

$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
$user_role_query = array();

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($user_roles); $i++) { 
    $user_role_query[] = array(
        'key'=>'attribution_roles',
        'value' => $user_roles[$i],
        'compare'=>'='
    );
}
```

I suggest read [WP_Query page in WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for details about comparison methods, relation ways, etc.

Hope it works for you ;)

Comment: I already tested this `'compare'=>'='` but it return me no results on the query.
If I keep LIKE, I get results. I think if we use the Equal, we need to rework the function.

Comment: Any ideas on what could happen (See my EDIT) ?