# If two first numbers exist in wp_meta_query value

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I want to display a Custom post Type "Companies" filtered by zipcode.

In my CPT I have an ACF field called 'companies_zip_code', their values looks like this :

```
29200
29860
35000
22350
...
```

**I want to display only companies where their companies_zip_code begins with `29`**

So I write this WP_QUery :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'companies',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'company_address_zip_code',
            'value' => 29,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        )
     )
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

With that I want to display only companies with zipcodes like this : `29200,29500,29860 etc..`
But it does not work

Thanks for your help !

Comment: If the answer helped you to solve your issue, please mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the REGEX compare option for the meta_query, like so:

```php
 'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'company_address_zip_code',
            'value'     => '^29@',
            'compare'   => 'REGEXP',
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hi ! The Regex does not work, it returns nothing

Answer (score 1):

In `meta_query` Change:

```
    'value' => 29,
    'compare' => 'LIKE',
```

to

```
    'value' => array(29000, 29999),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
```

Change two numbers in `value` accordingly to range of zip codes you want.

More info can be found on this [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70864/meta-query-compare-operator-explanation).